# Can this sql query be written better

Tags: mysql

I have got this SQL query and I was wondering if there's a better way to write the queries.

The query below creates the first table and selects attributes where cacount=1, second_ca selects attribute where cacount= 2, exams select attributes from the exams table. Finally, create the total score table that combines the scores from first_ca and second_ca.

```
WITH
  first_ca AS (
  SELECT
    studentid,
    name,
    subject,
    classroom,
    session,
    term,
    cacount,
    score
  FROM
    analysis.catable
  WHERE
    cacount = 1 ),
  second_ca AS (
  SELECT
    studentid,
    name,
    subject,
    classroom,
    session,
    term,
    cacount,
    score
  FROM
    analysis.catable
  WHERE
    cacount = 2 ),
  exam AS (
  SELECT
    studentid,
    name,
    subject,
    classroom,
    session,
    term,
    score
  FROM
   analysis.exams ),
  total_scores AS (
  SELECT
    fca.studentid AS Studentid,
    fca.name AS Name,
    fca.subject AS Subject,
    fca.classroom AS Classroom,
    fca.term AS Term,
    fca.session AS Session,
    fca.score AS First_CA,
    sca.score AS Second_CA,
    ROUND(fca.score + sca.score, 2) AS Total_CA,
    ex.score AS Exam,
    ROUND(fca.score + sca.score + ex.score, 2) AS Total_Score
  FROM
    exam AS ex
  JOIN
    first_ca AS fca
  ON
    ex.studentid = fca.studentid
    AND ex.name = fca.name
    AND lower(ex.subject)=lower(fca.subject)
    AND ex.session=fca.session
    AND ex.term=fca.term
  JOIN
    second_ca AS sca
  ON
    ex.studentid = sca.studentid
    AND ex.name = sca.name
    AND lower(ex.subject)=lower(sca.subject)
    AND ex.session=sca.session
    AND ex.term=sca.term
  ORDER BY
    ex.classroom )
```

schema for both tables are

```
table_name:catable

id          INTEGER NULLABLE    
name        STRING  NULLABLE    
studentid   INTEGER NULLABLE    
score       FLOAT   NULLABLE    
subject     STRING  NULLABLE    
account     INTEGER NULLABLE    
classroom   STRING  NULLABLE    
term        INTEGER NULLABLE    
session     STRING  NULLABLE

table_name:exams

id           INTEGER    NULLABLE    
name         STRING     NULLABLE    
studentid    INTEGER    NULLABLE    
score        FLOAT      NULLABLE    
subject      STRING     NULLABLE    
classroom    STRING     NULLABLE    
term         INTEGER    NULLABLE    
session      STRING     NULLABLE
```

Comment: Keyword: conditional aggregation

Comment: i feel like `classroom` is missing in `ON` clause of `JOIN`s - please confirm - this can change the way of refactoring above query

Comment: also, are you asking for mySQL or BigQuery - those are two quite different!

Comment: I am asking for MySQL. The classroom is not missing on the join statement.